# Evaluating a function using numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

What is the significance of the return part when evaluating functions? Why is this necessary?

Comment: fix your indentation!

Comment: Apologies, I'm confused -- do you mean I have unnecessary spaces somewhere?

Comment: You had a few that I fixed, but you should really create a minimal viable example that shows up your issue clearly. And your `f1` function does not make sense returning an assignment.

Comment: try `dfdx[x==0]`

Answer (score 0):

You give the answer. `x[0]` is `-1.0`,  and you want the value at the middle of the array.`np.linspace is the good  function to build such series of values :

```
def f1(x):
    g = np.sin(math.pi*np.exp(-x))
    return g

n = 1001 # odd !
x=linspace(-1,1,n) #x[n//2] is 0
f1x=f1(x)
df1=np.diff(f1(x),1)
dx=np.diff(x)

df1dx = - math.pi*np.exp(-x)*np.cos(math.pi*np.exp(-x))[:-1] # to discard last element

# In [3]: np.allclose(df1/dx,df1dx,atol=dx[0])
# Out[3]: True
```

As an other tip, numpy arrays are more efficiently and readably used without loops.

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is right: `dfdx[0]` is indeed the first value in that array, so according to your code that would correspond to evaluating the derivative at `x=-1.0`.

To know the correct index where x is equal to 0, you will have to look for it in the `x` array.

One way to find this is the following, where we find the index of the value where |x-0| is minimal (so essentially where x=0 but float arithmetic requires taking some precautions) using `argmin`  :

```
index0 = np.argmin(np.abs(x-0))
```

And we then get what we want, dfdx at the index where x is 0 :

```
print dfdx[index0]
```

An other but less robust way regarding float arithmetic trickery is to do the following:

```
# we make a boolean array that is True where x is zero and False everywhere else
bool_array = (x==0) 
# Numpy alows to use a boolean array as a way to index an array
# Doing so will get you the all the values of dfdx where bool_array is True 
# In our case that will hopefully give us dfdx where x=0
print dfdx[bool_array] 
# same thing as oneliner
print dfdx[x==0]
```